# Plastic SCM Unity Project workstation

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

I have been attempting to create a collaborative unity project, and after finding out that unity has migrated to plastic SCM entirely (To my knowledge) and getting tons of errors for attempting to use collaborate int the latest version (2022.1.20f1) I now managed to get to a point where I need to create a Plastic SCM workstation for my unity project, how does one do that?

For those curious, the error said: [Collab] Collab service is deprecated and has been replaced with PlasticSCM

And this error infinitely repeated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following resolve this:

- Make sure you have the latest version of the Version Control package in Package Manager.
- Navigate to the Services window and disable the Collaborate service.
- Restart the Editor, if you are alerted to migrate your project, please do so.
- Either way, you should now have access to the Plastic SCM window via the Window > Plastic SCM menu option.

If you keep getting the errors you should reach to PlasticSCM support directly.